# OnTouch Event listener is not working after Rotation

Tags: android, android-layout, rotation, ontouchlistener

i want to rotate a relative layout by a rotation button.

this is my code

main.java
                imageContainer = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.imageContainer);

```
            rotateBTN = (Button)findViewById(R.id.rotate);

            rotateBTN.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            final float xc = imageContainer.getWidth() / 2;
            final float yc = imageContainer.getHeight() / 2;

            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

            imageContainer.clearAnimation();

            mCurrAngle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(x - xc, yc - y));

            break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

            mPrevAngle = mCurrAngle;
            mCurrAngle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(x - xc, yc - y));

            animate(mPrevAngle, mCurrAngle, 0);

            break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP : {
            rotate = false;

            mPrevAngle = mCurrAngle = 0;

            break;
            }
            }

            return true;
            }
            });

private void animate(double fromDegrees, double toDegrees, long durationMillis) {
                    final RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation((float) fromDegrees, (float) toDegrees,
                            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

                    rotate.setDuration(durationMillis);
                    rotate.setFillEnabled(true);
                    rotate.setFillAfter(true);
                   imageContainer.startAnimation(rotate);
                //     imageView2.startAnimation(rotate);
                    System.out.println(mCurrAngle);
                }
```

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/onlyImage"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">


            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            />

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <Button
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/rotate"
            />


            </RelativeLayout>
```

by this code, i am able to rotate the RelativeLayout. But the problem is that after rotating first time (rotate button also rotates because it is inside my RelativeLayout) ontouch event is not called on new position of my rotate button but if i touch the top left corner of my relative layout ( initial position of my button) onTouch listener works fine.

plz help me find the issue. any suggestion would be appreciated :) 
[this is my relative layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLzwR.png)

P.S i want to do something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WX9Mj.png)

Comment: I may just guess because I am not really familiar with your code but I on configuration change your activity (=context) gets destroyed and maybe you don't reset your ``onTouchListener``?

Comment: i have edited my question containing the code

Comment: when this posted code is invoked ? Like @finki said maybe it's not invoked when you change the perspective of screen. Activity became destroyed when you changing perspective of screen, put Toast inside method and check if it's invoked.

Comment: this code is in my onCreate method

Comment: code is invoked when i click the initial position of my button whether the button is there or not.

Comment: you should never invoke when clicking on positions ;) and whatever your calculation for position is, it's another x/y in landscape.

Comment: @finki dude u r not getting my point. please review the image i have posted. the problem is if i rotate the button and leaves it in top left corner than it is working all good but if i rotate and after rotation the button got a new position even than the ontouch listener called when i touch the upper left corner

Comment: so why don't u set an onClickListener to the button instead of the onTouchListener like you are supposed to do?

Comment: somebody plz help guys. i have added one more image plz review it